# cannot use Context as type "handlerfunc" gin-gonic

Tags: go

This has been bugging me for a long time. I'm using gin-gonic and everytime I try and use `go run main.go`, this compile error always appears:

> cannot use properties.Pong (type
>   func(*"github.com/carlqt/geodude/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin".Context)) as type "github.com/gin-gonic/gin".HandlerFunc in argument to
>   router.RouterGroup.GET

But when I use Visual Studio Code terminal and run the `go run`, it works.

here's the main.go file https://gist.github.com/carlqt/c5f6b0d127c1ca124cf2fe8d620976a1

And here's the property.go file: https://gist.github.com/carlqt/6edadf1dedc63b4b4e231891cae8e9a5

My project structure looks like this

[image]

*Edit*
Adding `go env` for the terminal in VS Code and my terminal. I will put them on screenshot as to avoid human error

VS Code terminal:
[image]

iterm2 Terminal:
[image]

**Note**
The issue can be avoided, as well, if I put the HandlerFunc functions from the properties folder to main.go file.

Comment: Does `go build` work ? What argument(s) do you pass to `go run` both in your terminal and VS Code's.

Comment: I run `go run main.go` on both terminal. I will edit my question

Comment: What is value of `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT` in both terminal ?

Comment: They're both 1. I will post the value of `go env`

Comment: For me this has always been a result of packages missing from vendor/, try downloading all unvendored packages with `go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor; cd geodude; govendor fetch +external` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, sorry about all this mess but what worked for me is to uninstall `Go` and reinstall it again. Previously, `Go` was installed on my machine using Homebrew. When I reinstalled it, I used google's mac installer. Now all was fine again.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
govendor add +e
```